# class that extends from a generic type parameter (type variable)?

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

Is it possible to make a class extends from a generic type?

I want to subclass different components, either with `implements` or `extends` to add uniform functionality to all the subclasses.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
class MyTable extends MyAbstractComponent<JTable> {...}
class MyPanel extends MyAbstractComponent<JPanel> {...}
```

```
    MyAbstractComponent t = new MyTable();
    MyAbstractComponent p = new MyPanel();
    container.add(t);
    container.add(p);
```

In this case, how would I formulate `MyAbstractComponent`?
I tried the following, but it gives me the error "Found type: parameter C. Expected: class":

```
abstract class MyAbstractComponent<C extends Component> extends C {...}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `C`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Let subclasses extend from C. So I can, for example, do getSelectedRows() inside MyTable because C is JTable there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already got a good answer from the compiler, so it is not possible to let a class extend a type parameter. A type parameter is not a class. Instead of `abstract class MyAbstractComponent<C extends Component> extends C {...}` I would simply leave out the generics (not so useful here) or write:

```
abstract class MyAbstractComponent<C extends Component> extends Component {...}
```

**Remark about the wish for overriding `getSelectedRows()`:**

This could only be possible in a JTable subclass, but not in your panel subclass. In this case I recommend another approach:

1. Define MyAbstractComponent as interface.
2. Redefine your subclasses.

   class MyTable extends JTable implements MyAbstractComponent // here override getSelectedRows()
   class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MyAbstractComponent

If you already have some method implementations in your MyAbstractComponent then consider to move this code in a helper class which would be called by MyTable and MyPanel. Generics are not really so useful in an environment (SWING) which does not use this language feature due to historic reasons.

Anyway, if you are interested in learning more about generics I recommend Angelika Langers tutorial and faqs about generics (just google).

Comment: So what I tried is not possible. Is there another way to achieve my goal?  I need to override certain methods in my classes so your approach is not possible. (for example, override getSelectedRows() in MyTable)

Comment: @Zom-B I have extended my answer for your use-case.

Comment: I considered that exact option, even wrote it in the question and deleted it before submitting. The problem is that you can't enforce subclasses to extend from a Component, so `container.add((Component)x)` may give a run-time error.

Comment: @Zom-B What type does your variable container have? If it is just `java.awt.Container`and regarding the fact that MyTable and MyPanel indirectly inherit from Component then `container.add(x)` should be possible (x = MyTable-instance or MyPanel-instance).

Comment: You're correct in your assumption. And what I mean is: what if someone makes `class MyEvilClass extends Integer implements MyAbstractComponent`?

Comment: Sure, MyEvilClass could not be added to your container. If you care about security this is even a good thing, isn't it? Anyway, security is rather an issue on the server side, not so much in a Swing environment.

Answer (score 0):

I did sth. similar for my DAO layer

```
public interface EntityDAO<E, I> {
    public boolean update(final E entity, Connection connection);
    public E getByID(I id, Connection connection);
    public boolean delete(final I identifier, Connection connection);
}

public abstract class AbstractEntityDAO<E extends Entity, I extends Number> implements EntityDAO<E, I> {

    @Override
    public boolean update(E entity, Connection connection) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public E getByID(I id, Connection connection) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(I identifier, Connection connection) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally the concrete subclass will define the types of the entity object.

```
public class AddressEntityDAO extends AbstractEntity<Address, Integer> {

    @Override
    public boolean update(Address entity, Connection connection) {
        return super.update(entity, connection);
    }

    @Override
    public Address getByID(Integer id, Connection connection) {
        return super.getByID(id, connection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Integer identifier, Connection connection) {
        return super.delete(identifier, connection);
    }
}
```